# Boost.Asio: How to write a custom AsyncReadStream?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-asio

I've written a program that (amongst other things) creates child processes and receives notifications from them by listening to their stdout. This interprocess communication mechanism is fine, but I'm struggling with deadlocks.

I thought I could use Boost.Asio (that I already use for networking purpose in other parts of my program) and its Proactor Pattern implementation to make my program (mainly) single-threaded. By doing so, I wouldn't have to bother with thread synchronization anymore.

To do so, my guess is that I have to write a custom [AsyncReadStream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncReadStream.html) type (which would call Windows' ReadFile() in a thread) that I could use along with the asio::async_read_*() functions. My problem is that I have no idea of how to implement the async_read_some() member function of the AsyncReadStream concept. What am I supposed to do with the [MutableBufferSequence](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/MutableBufferSequence.html) reference the function receives?

Is that the correct approach? If so, how am I supposed to implement async_read_some()? Or maybe this isn't the correct approach and I have no other choice than writting a whole custom service?

Comment: Why can't you just use `asio::windows::random_access_handle` etc? Take a look at [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/windows/transmit_file.cpp).

Comment: @IgorR. The anonymous pipes used to retrieve the stdout of a process aren't randome-accessible, so windows::random_access_handle doesn't fit my need. I can't use windows::stream_handle either, because it doesn't support anonymous pipes (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/windows/stream_handle.html)).

Comment: I've done this with a [`stream_descriptor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/posix__stream_descriptor.html) on Linux and Mac, does this concept not work on Windows?

Comment: @SamMiller: Since it's located in the posix namespace, I guess it doesn't, unfortunately.

Comment: I know this is quite old but I managed to create a custom AsyncReadStream. You can take a look at it here https://github.com/raldone01/CustomAsioAsyncStreams.

Answer (score 0):

Interprocess communication via pipes is implemented in [Boost.Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process0.5). Although the library is not a part of Boost yet.